# How to draw elegant figure in such a way?

Tags: graph, figure

Recently, I browsed into the news web site and found this article about 2011. The thing attracts me is the figure they use to show the data, please check the picture below. I think it is beautiful and anyone knows how to make the graph in such a way?

http://www.zerohedge.com/news/summarizing-2011-nine-easy-charts?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zerohedge%2Ffeed+%28zero+hedge+-+on+a+long+enough+timeline%2C+the+survival+rate+for+everyone+drops+to+zero%29

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [zerohedge.com](http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/images/user5/imageroot/2011/12/2.png))</sub>

It seems like not from excel and google spreadsheet as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found tableau as a software to do my thing. It is beautiful

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery to draw charts like that you can see some of the plugins [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/)

Comment: are you sure it is the tool to make those figure above? THanks

Comment: By the way, I do not need itneractive figure or UI. I just need elegant graphs like above.